# Threads in java - use sleep inside run

Tags: java, multithreading

I want, after the print process, to stop the number of seconds registered, but when I run the play function, it does not reach sleep.
I can make the play function sleep, but I want to run `thread.sleep()` directly in the run function. Is it possible and how can I achieve this?

I have the following code:

```
public class Player implements Runnable {
    private String name;
    private String MusicalInstrument;
    Player(String name, String MusicalInstrument) {
        this.name = name;
        this.MusicalInstrument = MusicalInstrument;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            play();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void play() {
        while (true) {
            // print a message
            System.out.println(name + " is playing " + MusicalInstrument);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have an infinite loop and don't understand why it's infinite?

Comment: The issue is not the `sleep`, it's the `while(true)`

Comment: As a nitpick, `MusicalInstrument` should be `musicalInstrument` since it is not a class name.

Comment: You should review [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 5):

You are just continuously going to print because your while() runs indefinitely inside your play method and therefore you never return and reach the Thread.sleep method call inside your run() method. You should rework your methods to be more appropriate to what you are trying to do.

```
public void run() {
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            play();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public void play() {
    System.out.println(name + " is playing " + MusicalInstrument);
}
```